# New website won't load with error message HTTP 500.0 and urlscan failed

Tags: urlscan

I am getting following error on a new website created on IIS. I am able to see URL Rewrite deployed on this IIS instance. But the new website is not configured to use it. Please find the screen shot of the error message also attached. I searched across numerous forums and no find. I vaguely remember somehow fixed this issue previously, may be 1 year back or so . Since there is no log of the solution traced anywhere, I am in the same bad situation once gain. Please help me if anybody solved this kind of problem.
[image: GetFilterVersion_urlScan_500.0_Error_IIS]

Thanks in advance
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to make out what is going wrong. IIS is adding dependency on URLScan by default when a new website is created, but not sure why. I was able to see this in ISAPI Filters (Please refer attached screen shot). Everything worked fine once I removed URLScan from ISAPI filters.[image]